# What is the appropriate way to implement diverse callbacks?

Tags: c++

```
class Base{
template <typename F>
void Foo(int x, int y, F callback) {

    int z, w;
    std::string str;
    /*

       do a lot of works get value of str, z and w

    */
    
    callback();
    /*
    or callback(z, w);
    or callback(str);
    */
}

int main() {

    Foo(1, 2, [](){
      std::cout << "no parameter";
    });

    Foo(1, 2, [](int z, int w){
      std::cout << z << w<< "two parameters";
    });

    Foo(1, 2, [](string str){
      std::cout << str.size() << "string parameter";
    });
}
```

Originally I had several almost identical functions, but there were still some differences inside each that couldn't be merged.

I wanted to handle those differences by passing different callbacks, but couldn't find an  unified callback interface because the differences were not very similar.

Is there any elegant way to handle this situation? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Make all your callbacks accept all three parameters, even in they don't need them?  We need more context, really.  Redundant tags removed.

Comment: Your method with a template `F` allows any number of arguments, including none. ***But*** you need to decide what `Foo` really does, and what arguments (if any) it needs to pass.  If you want to do different things in the `Foo` function, then you really should have different functions all doing a single thing. If there is common code between the functions, then put those into other functions that the different `Foo` variants can call.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle a callback that could have one of three predetermined signatures?  Or are you asking how to call a function that could have any number of parameters of any type?

Comment: I know that it can be achieved by adding all the parameters required by all the callbacks, but I think adding a parameter that will not be used does not seem to be a good pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do type-dependant compile-time dispatch via [`std::is_invocable_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) or the [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept. Here's an example for your call.

```
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F>) {
      callback();
    } else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F,int,int>) {
      callback(z,w);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F,std::string>) {
      callback(str);
    }
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ajb74T3ez) with perfect forwarding for the callable.

---

Note that by changing the order you could select which callable gets precedence in case a functoid is callable different ways, e.g.:

```
struct Callable {
  void operator()(); // <- preferred above because of order
  void operator()(std::string);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that requires little changes on your code is to make all callbacks have the same signature.

Note that your code has many typos and not all is clear. I assume that `Foo` has the parameters to be passed to the callbacks. In case they come from outside `Foo` they should be bound to the callback before passing it to `Foo`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F> void Foo(F callback) { callback(0,0,{}); }

int main() {

    Foo([](int,int,const std::string&){
      std::cout << "no parameter";
    });

    Foo([](int z,int w,const std::string&){
      std::cout << z << w<< "two parameters";
    });

    Foo([](int,int,const std::string& str){
      std::cout << str.size() << "string parameter";
    });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s4M8oe3xq)

As mentioned in a comment, when the callbacks are too different in signatures you should reconsider whether it makes sense to handle them via a single `Foo` in the first place. How to proceed if the callback do have different signatures depends on details. The next most simple approach would be to have different overloads of `Foo` each handling callbacks with fixed signature.